# Lovasz theta of even cycle

Tags: graphs, information-theory

How does one show Lovasz theta of even $n$-cycle ($n$ is even) is of form $\frac{n}{2}$? Why is the Lovasz theta of such cycles not of form $\frac{n \cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{1+\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}$. Could someone provide a derivation for even cycle Lovasz theta number. It is clear that the Shannon Capacity is $\frac{n}{2}$. why is the cosine form tight only for odd cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lovász theta function is bounded between the independence number and the clique covering number (the chromatic number of the complementary graph). For even cycles, both numbers are $n/2$. For example, for the $6$-cycle with vertices $1,2,3,4,5,6$, there are independent sets of size $3$, e.g. $\{1,3,5\}$, and the graph can be covered with the $3$ cliques $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}$.

Comment: hmmm ok.. but would there be a semidefinite derivation of the same number? I am unable to get it.

Comment: You can take any of the definitions of the Lovász theta function and you will get the same thing, since all definitions result in the same number. You can try solving it for small $n$ on a computer and extrapolate.

Comment: I am getting what lovasz gets for n cycles but cos(pi/n)/(1+cos(pi/n)) is not 1/2 for even n. That is what I am missing.

Comment: So you are not finding the optimal solutions of the SDPs (or whatever formulation you are using). The solution for even cycles could be different from that of odd cycles.

Comment: Ok this is what I do. I represent the graph by independent coordinates of a vector space, define a Laplacian and use it to detect independent sets by identifying zeros of an inner product. I maximize a candidate vector which should zero on the innerprodcut and the boolean cube. I relax the cube to a sphere. I get the same solution for all n. The Lovasz number in its cosine form.

Comment: What you are computing is an upper bound on the theta function. The upper bound happens to be tight for odd cycles, but it isn't tight for even cycles. Using an SDP solver (or by hand) you can compute the theta function exactly on any given even cycle and see for yourself that you get $n/2$. Check out the various equivalent formulations of the theta function in the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number#Equivalent_expressions.

Comment: Just out of curiousity. Are you saying it happens to be tight for odd cycles because it matches capacity at $n=5$? and is there a reference where it says the upper bound is not tight for the theta function for even cycles(I understand the clique number and n/2 value for the actual theta)? I am just looking for a reference for the even cycle Lovasz number derivation from SDP.

Comment: As far as I understand, the Lovász theta function in fact isn't tight for odd cycles longer than 5, whereas for even cycles it is trivially tight. It's just that your method of estimating the theta function isn't tight for even cycles. Whatever you do, it doesn't result in the actual value of the theta function. You can compute the theta function by solving an SDP (you can even choose among several formulations), so I think there is no need for any reference – you can do it all on your own.

Comment: your comment: "the Lovász theta function in fact isn't tight for odd cycles longer than 5"..... this is new to me. Are you saying that it is known that the Lovasz number is not the capacity of C7, C9 and so on?

Comment: here C7 is 7-cycle and C9 is 9 cycle.

Comment: See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=DD51C68B5EFE62AD199272036E317926?doi=10.1.1.12.4552&rep=rep1&type=pdf for example. The Lovász bound cannot be tight since it is not of the form $\sqrt[a]{b}$ for integers $a,b$.

Comment: Hmmm I dont think even the capacity is of form $b^{\frac{1}{a}}$ for any finite $a$ for all $n>5$. We are just looking at some limiting numbers for capacity which could very well be the Lovasz number and this is exactly the famous open problem for even the next odd cycle on more than $5$ vertices.

Comment: According to the paper I link to, the theta bound can only be tight if it is of the form $b^{1/a}$. When it's not tight, the capacity could not be of that form.

Comment: Sorry. I looked at the paper. I am missing something. Could you please clarify? By Lovasz theta not being tight (say) at $n=7$ (as it is not of form $b^{\frac{1}{a}}$), are you you meaning to say $(1)$ capacity has to be of the form $b^{\frac{1}{a}}$ and $(2)$ Lovasz theta at $n=7$ is not of this form and hence Lovasz theta is not the capacity of $7$-cycle?

Comment: No, as the paper states, *if* the Lovász function is tight *then* the capacity has to be of the form $b^{1/a}$. Part (2) is correct.

Comment: Thank you. now it is more clear. I think by 'tight' you mean the case when Lovasz number equals capacity. And hence  if Lovasz number = capacity, both numbers have to be of form $b^{\frac{1}{a}}$? correct?

Comment: Right, that's what the paper claims, anyway.

Comment: Interesting. All I see in the paper is about a comment from Lovasz about the difficulty in ascertaining whether $\vartheta=\theta$ due to the fact that power of $\vartheta$ is never an integer for any general odd cycle bigger than a pentagon. From this I cannot infer,  Lovasz number = capacity $\implies$ capacity is of form $b^{\frac{1}{a}}$.

Comment: Indeed my question here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/184550/form-of-the-shannon-capacity-for-heptagon got a negative vote (I do not think what you think of is precise)

Answer (score 2):

See Lovasz' definition of theta in terms of orthonormal representations of graphs. Even cycles have an orthonormal representation in two dimensions in which the odd nodes are mapped to (0,1) and the even nodes are mapped to (1,0). Odd cycles, on the other hand, do not have two-dimensional orthonormal representations.  They have three-dimensional ones that take the form of an "umbrella".